# Errors in Simple C++ program

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04

This is the code, please help me if anything is wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char ch = 'A';
    int num = ch;
    cout << "The ASCII code for " << ch << "is " << num << "\n";
    cout << "Adding 1 to the character code : \n";
    ch = ch + 1;
    num = ch;
    cout << "The ASCII code for " << ch << "is " << num << "\n";
    return (0);
}
```

I get the errors like

```
ex1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
ex1.cpp:6:5: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
ex1.cpp:6:5: note: suggested alternative:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:62:18: note:   ‘std::cout’
```

Guys please correct my mistakes.

Comment: The suggested alternative is pretty much spot on.  Use `std::cout`

Comment: No, no, not again! Why not read a C++ tutorial before asking trivial questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The global `cout` object is defined in the `std` namespace (pretty much like all the stuff in the Standard Library, with only a few exceptions).

Thus, you can either fully qualify the name (and use `std::cout`):

```
std::cout << "The ASCII code for " << ch << "is " << num << "\n";
// ...
```

Or introduce a *using declaration*:

```
using std::cout;
cout << "The ASCII code for " << ch << "is " << num << "\n";
// ...
```

Avoid the **bad**, global using declaration:

```
using namespace std;
```

Which would import *all* symbols defined in the `std` namespace into the global namespace, thus leading to a high risk of name clashes. This is a *bad* programming practice and should be used only in limited situations.

Comment: One more doubt, We have to declare everything like 'cout' 'cin' using 'using std::cout' and 'using std::cin' ?
there are many declaration like these or these are the only two?

Comment: @prabuksara: It is a good programming practice to declare everything you need that way as long as this is not going to be too verbose. Of course, if there would be too many names from the `std` namespace that you are using, you could have a `using namespace std` declaration, but you should put that in a limited scope (i.e. inside functions), and not (for instance) at the global scope in a shared header. Otherwise, all the files that import that header will also import all the names from the `std` namespace.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `using std::cout;`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the iostream header provides these objects for you but only under the `std` namespace. Use a qualified name by prefixing them with `std::`:

```
std::cout << code;
```

It's commonly recommended that you do *not* use `using namespace std` because it introduces tokens into the global namespace. You're better off with using the namespace prefix as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::cout` or add the `std` namespace. Put this on the top of your file:

```
using namespace std;
```

Comment: `using namespace std` is more often than not a bad idea.

Comment: Okay, I get that, do you perhaps have some pointers that go a little more in depth?

Comment: There is a good discussion of the issue in this question: [Why is 'using namespace std;' considered a bad practice in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Answer (score -1):

`cout` is a stream defined in the namespace `std`. So when you use it you either have to write `std::cout` or you need a line `using std::cout` in global scope before your first usage of cout.

Comment: I don't think it is a function!